# selected item of listbox inserted into sql database using classic asp

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a asp form with a few text boxes and 10 list boxes in 10 rows.The user may select 5 list boxes out of 10...if they submit that form.it needs to insert that selected 5 rows..right now it insert all the 10 list boxes even if the remaining text boxes are not selected by the user.

Kindly help me the selected items get submitted.

Comment: what do you mean by a selected list box? Normally a listbox is either drop-down (in which case it always has a selected item) or single or multiple selection. Either way only the selected items get submitted.

Comment: it means..the selection of the list boxes..i mean what you said..please see to my fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/WLzm5/

Answer (score 0):

All your select elements seem to have distinct names.  You need to use Request.Form to collect your data, and you can use conditional statements to ignore boxes where nothing is selected.  Eg for your select box smpls3_frm, something like

```
if Request.Form("smpls3_frm") <> "" then
  sql= "insert into smpls (smpl_name) values ('"& Request.Form("smpls3_frm") & "')"
  conn.Execute(sql)
End If
```

I'm assuming you've already set up your database connection

Comment: Thanks John...please see to my fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/WLzm5/ ...in this out of 8 list boxes if they select 5 rows..it needs to get inserted instead of 8 rows..kindly help me

Comment: You need to replicate this for each of your 8 selects.  The "if" statement ensures that the insert query will only be executed if a value has been selected.